# Почему форма не отправляется puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://etfdb.com/members/login/?redirect_url=%2F');

    await page.$eval('#user_login', (elem) => {
        elem.value = 'login';
    });

    await page.$eval('#password', (elem) => {
        elem.value = 'password';
    });

    await page.click('#login-button');
    
    await page.screenshot({path: 'etf.png'})

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Проблема в том что при завершении ввода данных в поля и нажатия на кнопку отправить ничего не происходит. Что делать?

Answer (score 3):

Так происходит из-за того что форма на указанном сайте разрешает нажать кнопку "Login" только в случае если в поля логина и пароля введено хоть что-то, но эта проверка идёт на событие "input", которое не вызывается если задавать значение через `value`.

Как вариант можно напечатать значение через [`page.keyboard`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/c7d32cb92f7e3556a3dba51832ab9d6a07ddbf35/docs/api.md#class-keyboard):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        // просим показывать браузер
        // что бы можно было следить за процессом
        headless: false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://etfdb.com/members/login/?redirect_url=%2F');

    // кликаем по полю ввода что бы поймать фокус 
    await page.click('#user_login');
    // вводим логин с клавиатуры
    await page.keyboard.type('login');

    // аналогично с паролем
    await page.click('#password');
    await page.keyboard.type('password');

    await page.click('#login-button');
    
    // await page.screenshot({path: 'etf.png'})

    // await browser.close();
})();
```

Так же можно вызвать событие `input` самому.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        // просим показывать браузер
        // что бы можно было следить за процессом
        headless: false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://etfdb.com/members/login/?redirect_url=%2F');

    await page.$eval('#user_login', (elem) => {
        elem.value = 'login';
    });

    await page.$eval('#password', (elem) => {
        elem.value = 'password';
    });

    await page.$eval('#login-form', (elem) => {
        elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    })

    await page.click('#login-button');
    
    // await page.screenshot({path: 'etf.png'})

    // await browser.close();
})();
```