# Почему не активна кнопка отправки после ввода данных в поля на Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

есть код:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://etfdb.com/members/login/?redirect_url=%2F');

    await page.$eval('#user_login', (elem) => {
        elem.value = 'Alexyavorskiy2005-0711@mail.ru';
    });

    await page.$eval('#password', (elem) => {
        elem.value = 'alex07112005';
    });

    await page.click('#login-button');
    
    await page.screenshot({path: 'etf.png'})

    await browser.close();
})();
```

и после ввода данных в поля кнопка не активна хотя когда я лично зашел на сайт, ввел данные кнопка стала активной и на нее можно было нажать.

Comment: вам уже ответили https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1194166/2659

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему форма не отправляется puppeteer?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1194148/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-puppeteer)