# Как переделать код из JS в Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

```
const rows = document.querySelector('div#mobile_table_pills table')
          .querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

for (const row of rows) {
  const lastCellText = row.querySelector('[data-th="ETFdb Pro"]').innerText;
  if ( lastCellText === 'A+' || lastCellText === 'B+') {
    console.log(row.querySelector('[data-th="Symbol"]').innerText);
  }
}
```

Как переделать код из JS в Puppeteer?
А также добавить функционал перехода на следующую страницу, пока они не закончатся.

Вот ссылка на сайт https://etfdb.com/screener/

Вот попытка решения:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
import 'package:puppeteer/puppeteer.dart';

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        // просим показывать браузер
        // что бы можно было следить за процессом
        headless: false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://etfdb.com/members/login/?redirect_url=%2F');

    // кликаем по полю ввода что бы поймать фокус 
    await page.click('#user_login');
    // вводим логин с клавиатуры
    await page.keyboard.type('alexyavorskiy2005-0711@mail.ru');

    // аналогично с паролем
    await page.click('#password');
    await page.keyboard.type('alex07112005');

    await page.click('#login-button');

    await page.goto('https://etfdb.com/screener/#page=1&structure=ETF&dividend_frequency=Monthly');

    const rows = await page.$('div#mobile_table_pills table')
        .querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

    for (const row of rows) {
        const lastCellText = row.querySelector('[data-th="ETFdb Pro"]').innerText;
        if (lastCellText === 'A+' || lastCellText === 'B+') {
            console.log(row.querySelector('[data-th="Symbol"]').innerText);
        }
    }


    // await page.screenshot({path: 'etf.png'})

    // await browser.close();
})();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите, пожалуйста, ваши попытки

Comment: показал в вопросе!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> В последние дни вы завалили сайт вопросами, говорящими о том, что вы
> пока недостаточно хорошо понимаете основы JS и Web API, а уже
> пытаетесь работать со сложными инструментами типа puppeteer.

Алекс, я поддерживаю [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1194798/2659), который дал вам [vsemozhebuty](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1194798/2659). Увы, вам не хватает знания технологий, *ваш технический кругозор узок* и, как следствие, вы решаете задачу трудно, долго и плохо.

Решив обосновать этот тезис я взглянул на ваш код, на сайт https://etfdb.com/ и на попытки извлечь данные из тела страницы с помощью [puppeteer](/questions/tagged/puppeteer).

Страница `https://etfdb.com/screener/#page=1&structure=ETF&dividend_frequency=Monthly` и пагинация на ней работает не замысловато - каждая "страница" таблицы делает ajax запрос на сервер, получает данные и от них рисует таблицу.

Есть ajaх-запрос, есть данные, нет никакого смысла прыгать по dom-элементам и парсить разметку!

<sub>И то, что вы выбрали именно такой подход, говорит нам, тем, кто сопровождает ваши вопросы на ru.so, об узости вашего технического кругозора...</sub>

> Изучите систематически язык и Web API, после этого прочтите
> документацию по инструментам, которые вам нужны. Другого пути нет.
>
> Пытаться громоздить фрагмент кода на фрагмент,
> заимствуя их из чужих примеров и не понимая их сути, — это
> бессмысленное блуждание в потёмках.

Спасибо, что дочитали досюда.

---

С другой стороны - я ценю ваши настойчивые попытки разобраться! Они поверхностные, но настойчивые, это стоит решения.

Смотрите, сценарий прост:

1. Создаём браузер
2. Делаем логин вводом с клавиатуры, [как вам советовали в другом
   ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1194166/2659)

   При запросе страницы логина поставим `waitUntil: 'networkidle2'`, чтобы дождаться загрузки всех скриптов. Возможно это лишнее и форма сабмитися классически, а возможно запрос на аутентификацию выполняется js и тогда скрипты нужны. Я не стал разбираться, но ты можешь посмотреть!
3. В evaluate (т.е. внутри запущенного браузера) выполняем
   несколько ajax-запросов, получающих с сервера данные. API возвращает мета-информацию о номере страницы, количестве записей на странице, *и количестве страниц*. Знать количество страниц очень удобно так как мы можем сделать ровно такое количество запросов!

   И возвращаем всю коллекцию в место, вызвавшее evaluate.
4. Закрываем браузер
5. Работаем с данными

Протестировано Node.js v14.13.0, puppeteer 5.3.1.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const credentials = {
  login: 'alexyavorskiy2005-0711@mail.ru',
  password: 'alex07112005'
};

(async () => {
  try {
    await spy();
    process.exit(0);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
})();

async function spy() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(
    'https://etfdb.com/members/login/',
    { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 0 }
  );
  await page.click('#user_login');
  await page.keyboard.type(credentials.login);
  await page.click('#password');
  await page.keyboard.type(credentials.password);
  await page.click('#login-button');

  await promisify(setTimeout)(2000);

  const etfData = await page.evaluate(async () => {
    const sleep = (timeout = 500) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, timeout));

    let resultData = [];

    const fetchBody = {
      structure: ['ETF'],
      dividend_frequency: ['Monthly'],
      only: ['meta', 'data', 'count']
    };

    const fetchOptions = {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
      },
    };

    for (let i = 1, curr = 1; i<= curr; i++) {
      try {
        fetchBody.page = i;
        const res = await fetch(
          'https://etfdb.com/api/screener/',
          { ...fetchOptions, body: JSON.stringify(fetchBody) }
        );

        const json = await res.json();
        
        if (json) {
          if (json.data && Array.isArray(json.data)) {
            resultData = resultData.concat(json.data);
          }
          if (json.meta && 'total_pages' in json.meta && +json.meta.total_pages > 0) {
            curr = +json.meta.total_pages;
          }
        }

        await sleep(); // на всякий случай, вдруг там ограничение по количеству запросов
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }

    return resultData;
  });

  await browser.close();

  const filteringOverallRating = ['A+', 'A', 'A-', 'B+'];
  const etfABData = etfData.filter(({ overall_rating }) => filteringOverallRating.includes(overall_rating));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(etfABData, null, 2));
  console.log(`total items = ${etfData.length}, filtered items = ${etfABData.length}`);

  return etfABData;
}
```

В консоли:

```
[
  {
    "symbol": {
      "type": "link",
      "text": "BSAE",
      "url": "/etf/BSAE/"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "link",
      "text": "Invesco BulletShares 2021 USD Emerging Markets Debt ETF",
      "url": "/etf/BSAE/"
    },
    "mobile_title": "BSAE - Invesco BulletShares 2021 USD Emerging Markets Debt ETF",
    "price": "$25.37",
    "assets": "$10.12",
    "average_volume": "2,508",
    "ytd": "2.32%",
    "overall_rating": "A+",
    "asset_class": "Bond"
  },
  {
    "symbol": {
      "type": "link",
      "text": "QDIV",
      "url": "/etf/QDIV/"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "link",
      "text": "Global X S&P 500 Quality Dividend ETF",
      "url": "/etf/QDIV/"
    },
    "mobile_title": "QDIV - Global X S&P 500 Quality Dividend ETF",
    "price": "$23.40",
    "assets": "$5.71",
    "average_volume": "809",
    "ytd": "-11.17%",
    "overall_rating": "B+",
    "asset_class": "Equity"
  },
  ...
  ...
  ...
]

total items = 415, filtered items = 163
```

Comment: Отличный ответ, только пролог явно лишний. Его лучше комментарием оформить.

Comment: @0xdb о, кстати, у меня к тебе есть вопрос. сейчас напишу

Comment: _об узости вашего технического кругозора_, это тоже надо убрать, в ответе от подобного рода критики надо воздержаться. Ответы  не только для ТС, а те, кто будут читать из поисковика, зададутся вопросом - к чему это?.

Comment: нет, тут тот случай, когда это выражение используется не для критики, а в качестве термина, обозначающего состояние знаний и навыков топикстартера. дальнейший ответ предназначен исключительно для того, чтобы продемонстрировать, что знания и навыки 1) дают возможность выбирать подход к решению задачи 2) решать задачу.

Comment: Полностью согласен

Comment: _об узости вашего технического кругозора_, но так же лучше: _о том, что надо расширить технический кругозор в том-то том-то_ .

Comment: Ну ладно, если ТС согласен, то пусть будет, плюсанул. а где вопрос ко мне, в чате?

Comment: @0xdb я тебя понимаю, ответ, очевидно, что не отвечает стандартам so, но то, что предлагаешь ты, это - уже менторство, которым я не намерен заниматься.

Comment: _это - уже менторство_, как раз этим я и предлагаю не заниматься. Ответ должен быть нейтрален к уровню потенциального читателя. Формулировки могут быть "простонароодными" или более "технически сложными", это да, но это зависит от темы в целом и связанноого с ней уровня предпологаемого потенциального читателя.

Comment: @nörbörnën, этот код почему то перестал работать!
Выдает что отфильтровал только ноль

Comment: @Alex05 и почему я должен об этом знать? скорее всего или неполадки на сервисе, или у тебя закончился триальный период, или изменилось апи. я бы начал с того, что посмотрел на эту таблицу в web-e

Comment: @nörbörnën, думал ты поможешь

Comment: @Alex05 я дал тебе 3 гипотезы

Comment: @nörbörnën, спасибо сработало