# Почему выдает ошибку метод slice?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Переменная pagination существует но вот slice в консоле выводит ошибку
https://etfdb.com/screener/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что изучите основы JavaScript

Comment: Сделать это можно на [developer mozila](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/) или на [learn.javascript](https://learn.javascript.ru/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что тип переменной NodeList , который не Array. Сначала нужно в массив преобразовать.

Comment: а как преобразовать

Comment: Например использовать `Array.from()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199588/fastest-way-to-convert-javascript-nodelist-to-array

Comment: let list = await page.evaluate(async () => {
        let res = []
        let pagination = document.querySelectorAll('ul.pagination > li');
        pagination.push(res);
        console.log(res.slice(2, res.length - 2));
    });
тоже ошибка почему то

Comment: Всё по той же причине. Метод push есть у массива. А в вашей переменной не массив. Читайте про метод querySelectorAll и тип NodeList - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: let res = []
        let pagination = document.querySelectorAll('ul.pagination > li');
        pagination.from().push(res);
        console.log(res.slice(2, res.length - 2));
VM2610:3 Uncaught TypeError: pagination.from is not a function
    at <anonymous>:3:20

Comment: Ну теперь то что

Comment: Изучите основы JavaScript. Судя по вопросам вы не понимаете как он работает.

Answer (score 3):

Я рискну написать в ответе, хоть, наверное, это осудят. Но в комментарий не поместится.

В последние дни вы завалили сайт вопросами, говорящими о том, что вы пока недостаточно хорошо понимаете основы JS и Web API, а уже пытаетесь работать со сложными инструментами типа puppeteer.

Пока всё это похоже на такую ситуацию. Вы где-то как-то обрывками видите, как ездят на машине разные водители. И вот вы садитесь за руль, хотя не представляете себе устройство автомобиля, не проходили технику вождения и не учили ПДД. Вы на что-то нажимаете, что-то поворачиваете. У вас то что-то не работает, то вы резко трогаетесь и врезаетесь в столб. Вы обращаетесь к разным водителям, спрашивая, что делает эта кнопка, или почему этот рычаг делает не то, что вы хотите, или что это за знак. Или просто просите их сесть за ваш руль и подвезти вас куда-то. Всё это мучительно и для вас, и для других.

Изучите систематически язык и Web API, после этого прочтите документацию по инструментам, которые вам нужны. Другого пути нет, всё остальное сизифов труд. Пытаться громоздить фрагмент кода на фрагмент, заимствуя их из чужих примеров и не понимая их сути, — это бессмысленное блуждание в потёмках.

Прочтите https://learn.javascript.ru/ полностью, у вас всё прояснится, большая часть вопросов отпадёт, а оставшиеся станут осмысленными, на них легко будет отвечать.

Если же вы не собираетесь заниматься программированием, вам нужен лишь готовый скрипт, чтобы решить проблему, обратитесь на фриланс-биржу, чтобы кто-то его просто написал для вас.

Простите и не сочтите за грубость. Мне просто правда жалко смотреть, как вы мучаетесь уже который день, идя неправильным путём.

Comment: трогательно. я ещё добавил https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1194873/2659

Answer (score 0):

У типа NodeList, который возвращает вам document.querySelectorAll, нет метода slice.
Чтобы преобразовать NodeList в Array можно использовать следующий метод:

```
const array = Array.prototype.slice.call(pagination);
```

Comment: let pagination = document.querySelectorAll('ul.pagination > li');
        const array = Array.prototype.slice.call(pagination);
        console.log(array);
VM11706:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'array' has already been declared

Comment: @Alex05, как насчет просто перевести ошибку? `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'array' has already been declared` - "array" уже было объявлено.