# NodeJS : puppeteer / загрузить и переименовать файл

Tags: node.js, парсер, puppeteer, fs

Здравствуйте гуру NodeJS!
Как происходит работа на стороннем сайте через NodeJS.
Задача : Заполнить поле пароля в форме на стороннем сайте и отправить эту форму - if пароль верный, загрузить файл в папку /img на сервер .
Например :
вот сайт с формой ,
https://www.sendfilessecurely.com/getfile.aspx?id=ndyOmD32wTkmBY13XelV9pThl06ecdTTa5EH
если ввести пароль : 12345 и подтвердить форму , начнется скачивание файла в папку по умолчанию .

---

Вопрос : как указать директорию сохранения файла , а так же переименовать его?

---

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.sendfilessecurely.com/getfile.aspx?id=ndyOmD32wTkmBY13XelV9pThl06ecdTTa5EH');
    //заполняем input пароль
    await page.type("#ContentPlaceHolder0_password","12345");
    //Нажимаем на кнопку
    await page.click("#ContentPlaceHolder0_btnSubmit");

})();
```

Comment: для скачивания такого файла можно использовать headless-браузеры, например puppeteer. в моём [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1194873) есть пример использования `page.keyboard.type` для ввода логина и/или пароля

Comment: Спасибо, использовал ваш пример / отредактировал свой вопрос .
Осталось решить с загрузкой в необходимую директорию ./img и переименовать скачанный файл ,  это возможно с puppeteer ?